# AngularJS filter items by array of properties (checkbox)

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-filter

I would like to filter the results by multiple properties.
My code:

```js
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular.
  module('myApp', []).
  filter('byFeatures', byFeatures).
  controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);

  function byFeatures() {
    return function (items, conditions) {
      if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(conditions).length === 0) {
        return items;
      }
      var filtered = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var item = items[i];
        angular.forEach(item.features, function (feature) {
          if (conditions[feature.name] !== undefined && conditions[feature.name][feature.value] !== undefined) {
            if (conditions[feature.name][feature.value]) {
              //filtered.push(item);
              filtered[item.id] = item;
            }
          }
        });
      }
      //console.log(filtered);
      return filtered;
    };
  };

  function MyCtrl($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.allProducts = [{
        id: 0,
        name: "Product A",
        features: [{
            name: "Brand",
            value: "Apple"
          },
          {
            name: "Memory",
            value: "16"
          },
          {
            name: "Color",
            value: "Black"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Product B",
        features: [{
            name: "Brand",
            value: "Apple"
          },
          {
            name: "Memory",
            value: "32"
          },
          {
            name: "Color",
            value: "Black"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Product C",
        features: [{
            name: "Brand",
            value: "Nokia"
          },
          {
            name: "Memory",
            value: "16"
          },
          {
            name: "Color",
            value: "Black"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Product A",
        features: [{
            name: "Brand",
            value: "Samsung"
          },
          {
            name: "Memory",
            value: "16"
          },
          {
            name: "Color",
            value: "Black"
          }
        ]
      },
    ];
    $scope.filters = [{
        name: "Brand",
        values: [
          "Apple",
          "Nokia",
          "Samsung",
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Memory",
        values: [
          "16",
          "32",
        ]
      },
    ];
    $scope.currentFilter = {};
    $scope.$watch('currentFilter', function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
      //console.log(newValue);

      $scope.products = $filter('byFeatures')($scope.allProducts, newValue);
    }, true);

  };
}());
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" class="ng-scope">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl" style="width: 100%;">
    
    <div style="width: 50%; float: left;">
      <h2>Available Phones</h2>
      <div ng-repeat="product in products">
        <h3>
          {{ product.name }}
        </h3>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="feature in product.features">
            {{feature.name}} : {{feature.value}}
          </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 50%; float: left;">
      <h2>Filters</h2>
      <pre>{{currentFilter|json}}</pre>
      <div ng-repeat="filter in filters">
        <span>{{filter.name}}</span>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="value in filter.values">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="currentFilter[filter.name][value]"> {{value}}<br>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body></html>
```

If i filter by brand "Apple" are displayed 2 phones with brand "apple" (16 and 32 memory) - its ok. But if i add second filter by memory "16" - will must display only 1 phone apple with memory "16".
How to do it? . Link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/budko1989/tg4can4u/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing the opposite from what you want: You are checking that the product contains a valid property for **one** of the items (Brand *or* Memory). What we need to do is check if the product has a valid property for **all** the items (Brand *and* Memory).

It would be enough to change the loop inside the function byFeatures in order to find every relevant condition (When its value is true!) and make sure that our product has one of the selected properties for each, Brand and Memory. Here you can see the right snippet:

```js
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular.
  module('myApp', []).
  filter('byFeatures', byFeatures).
  controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);

  function byFeatures() {
    return function (items, conditions) {
      if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(conditions).length === 0) {
        return items;
      }
      var filtered = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var item = items[i],
          hasProperties = true;

        angular.forEach(conditions, function (value, key) {
          for (var i = 0; i < item.features.length; i++) {
            if (item.features[i].name === key && (!value.hasOwnProperty(item.features[i].value) || !value[item.features[i].value])) {
              for (var j in value) {
                if (value[j]) {
                  hasProperties = false;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        });

        if (hasProperties) {
          filtered.push(item);
        }
      }
      //console.log(filtered);
      return filtered;
    };
  };

  function MyCtrl($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.allProducts = [{
        id: 0,
        name: "Product A",
        features: [{
            name: "Brand",
            value: "Apple"
          },
          {
            name: "Memory",
            value: "16"
          },
          {
            name: "Color",
            value: "Black"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Product B",
        features: [{
            name: "Brand",
            value: "Apple"
          },
          {
            name: "Memory",
            value: "32"
          },
          {
            name: "Color",
            value: "Black"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Product C",
        features: [{
            name: "Brand",
            value: "Nokia"
          },
          {
            name: "Memory",
            value: "16"
          },
          {
            name: "Color",
            value: "Black"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Product A",
        features: [{
            name: "Brand",
            value: "Samsung"
          },
          {
            name: "Memory",
            value: "16"
          },
          {
            name: "Color",
            value: "Black"
          }
        ]
      },
    ];
    $scope.filters = [{
        name: "Brand",
        values: [
          "Apple",
          "Nokia",
          "Samsung",
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Memory",
        values: [
          "16",
          "32",
        ]
      },
    ];
    $scope.currentFilter = {}; //$scope.filters;
    $scope.$watch('currentFilter', function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
      $scope.products = $filter('byFeatures')($scope.allProducts, newValue);
    }, true);

  };
}());
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" class="ng-scope">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl" style="width: 100%;">
    <div style="width: 50%; float: left;">
      <h2>Available Phones</h2>
      <div ng-repeat="product in products">
        <h3>
          {{ product.name }}
        </h3>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="feature in product.features">
            {{feature.name}} : {{feature.value}}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 50%; float: left;">
      <h2>Filters</h2>
      <pre>{{currentFilter|json}}</pre>
      <div ng-repeat="filter in filters">
        <span>{{filter.name}}</span>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="value in filter.values">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="currentFilter[filter.name][value]"> {{value}}<br>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I also changed the way you were adding the new product to the filtered array. Otherwise, if the ID of the only item is 2, the array would keep the first 2 positions as 'undefined' and this would cause troubles through the ngRepeat iterations